# PHP check occurences of a character inside a string

Tags: php, regex

I got strings like these:

```
car-122-334
bike-123
boat
```

I want to know how many "hyphens" in the string. if there is 2 hyphens return 2, if 0 hyphen return 0...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From php.net: [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
int substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 [, int $length ]] )
```

For example:

```
$text = "car-122-334";
echo substr_count ($text, '-'); // --> 2
```

Answer (score 6):

use the `substr_count` method in PHP. No need for regex.

```
echo substr_count($text, '-');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php.

substr_count will give you what you expect `$count = substr_count($str, "-");`